# when i run .onclick, it runs once, and then it doesnt work again

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

to my understanding, .onclick, should work each time I click the button, however this is only working once. This is my code so far

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.onclick = moveLeft;

function moveLeft() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box1");
  var pos = 200;
  if (pos < 500) {
    pos = pos + 50
    box.style.right = pos + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 650px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

#left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

#right {
  left: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
}

#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.grid {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, transparent 49px, #88F 49px, #88F 50px), repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent, transparent 49px, #88F 49px, #88F 50px);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tetris</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="left" onclick="moveLeft()"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

like I said, it works, but only once, it shifts the box to the left one square, but it shouldn't stop until after 5 squares.
please help...

Comment: the function is working but since your `var pos = 200;` is same everytime, you may see `box1` at the same position after first time, try changing value of `var pos` dynamically.

Comment: ^ if you make `pos` global then it won't reset every time, allowing it to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is right, your `pos` variable revalue to 200 when you click your button everytime.
So it is just from 200 to 250 everytime.it look like same everytime.
try like this:

```
var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.onclick = moveLeft;

var pos = 200;
function moveLeft() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box1");
  if (pos < 500) {
    pos = pos + 50
    box.style.right = pos + "px";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `pos` variable is defined inside the `moveLeft` function. Every time the function is executed, the `pos` is always 200. Define it outside the `moveLeft` function.

Answer (score 1):

Either make `pos` global as in below snippet.

Or set it dynamically within the function.

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.onclick = moveLeft;
var pos = 200;

function moveLeft() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box1");

  if (pos < 500) {
    pos = pos + 50
    box.style.right = pos + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 650px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

#left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

#right {
  left: 250px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
}

#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.grid {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, transparent 49px, #88F 49px, #88F 50px), repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent, transparent 49px, #88F 49px, #88F 50px);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tetris</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="left" onclick="moveLeft()"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```